# $\binom{2^{n+1}}{2^{n}}(n\in\mathbb{N})$ is not a multipleof four

Tags: combinatorics

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: $\binom{2^{n+1}}{2^{n}}(n\in\mathbb{N})$ is not a multipleof four

I tried to solve(by Induction) this problem  but I can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Recall that $$\binom{2^{n+1}}{2^n}=\frac{2^{n+1}!}{2^n!\cdot2^n!}\;,$$ and count the factors of $2$ in $2^{n+1}!$ and in $2^n!\cdot2^n!$. If you don’t see right away a general formula for the number of factors of $2$ in $2^k!$, calculate the number in $2^k!$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$, say, by hand and try to spot the pattern.

Comment: genius. You are fast Brian! good eye!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for a combinatorial argument.

**Lemma.** $\binom{2^n}{k}$ is even if $1\le n$ and $0<k<2^n$.

**Proof.** True for the base case $n=1$.

Assume it's true for $n-1$ and that now, we are picking $k$ spots out of a line of $2^n$. The pattern can be asymmetrical or symmetrical. Each asymmetrical pattern can be matched with its mirror-image, so there are an even number of those. If the pattern is symmetrical, then $k$ is even, and we can determine the pattern by filling the left-hand side in $\binom{2^{n-1}}{k/2}$ ways; and this number is even by assumption.